# Permanent root access for Android emulator from 2.1 to latest version

Tags: android

I am trying to root the android emulator for this , I went through almost all blogs and posts but all are mention about only root access.

I want to root android emulator permanently  for above mention versions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: for my curiosity: why would you want to root an emulator ?

Comment: Thats project requirement, which is related to host entries.